# Find connected components in array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, math

I'd like to apply some kind of special pattern find algorithm using Swift.

Some explanations:

I'm getting a simple 1-dimensional array that could look like this:

```
var array = [ 
               "0000000000000000000",
               "0000001110000000000",
               "0000011111000000000",
               "0000001110000000000",
               "0000000000000000000",
               "0001100000000000000",
               "0001100000000011000",
               "0011100000000011000",
               "0000000000000000000"
            ]
```

And I'd like to extract the connected areas of "1"-characters (connected components).

Have a look at this:

```
       111
      11111
       111

 11
 11         11
111         11
```

---

I'd like to get as result a multidimensional array that includes all x/y-positions of the single components.

```
var result = [
                [ [6,1], [7,1], [8,1], [5,2], [6,2], [7,2], [8,2], [9,2], [6,3], [7,3], [8,2] ] // positions of the first area (the biggest one on top)

                [ [3,5], [4,5], [3,6], [4,6], [2,7], [3,7], [4,7] ] // area bottom left

                [ [14,6], [15,6], [14,7], [15,7] ] // area bottom right (smallest area)
             ]
```

---

I've coded the function for javascript. You can find the code right here:

```js
var matrix = [
  "0000000000000000000",
  "0000001110000000000",
  "0000011111000000000",
  "0000001110000000000",
  "0000000000000000000",
  "0001100000000000000",
  "0001100000000011000",
  "0011100000000011000",
  "0000000000000000000"
]


Array.prototype.extract_components_positions = function(offset) {
  var array = this.map(item => item.split('')).map(str => Array.from(str, Number)),
    default_value = 0,
    result_object = {}

  function test_connection(array, i, j) {
    if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
      if (!result_object[default_value]) result_object[default_value] = [];
      result_object[default_value].push([j, i]);
      array[i][j] = 1;
      for (var k = offset; k > 0; k--) {
        test_connection(array, i + k, j); // left - right
        test_connection(array, i, j + k); // top - bottom
        test_connection(array, i - k, j); // right - left
        test_connection(array, i, j - k); // bottom - top
      }
      return true
    }
  }
  array.forEach(function(a) {
    a.forEach(function(b, i, bb) {
      bb[i] = -b
    })
  });
  array.forEach(function(a, i, aa) {
    a.forEach(function(b, j, bb) {
      test_connection(aa, i, j) && default_value++
    })
  })
  return [result_object];
}



var result = matrix.extract_components_positions(1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

but I have a big problems translating this Javascript code into Swift!

```
 func extract_components_positions(matrix: [[String]],offset: Int) {
    var array = [[]]  // no idea how to use map to split the array from ["0011100"],... to ["0","0","1","1",...], ...
    var default_value = 0,
        result_object = [[Int]()]

    func testconnection(matrix: [[String]], i: Int, j: Int) -> [[Int]] {
        if (Int(array[i][j] as! Int) == -1) {
            array[i][j] = 1
            for var k in offset...0 {
                testconnection(matrix: array, i: i+k, j: j) // error: "Cannot convert value of type '[[Any]]' to expected argument type '[[String]]'"
                testconnection(matrix: array, i: i, j: j+k)
                testconnection(matrix: array, i: i-k, j: j)
                testconnection(matrix: array, i: i, j: j-k)
            }
        }
    }
    array.forEach { (a) in
        a.forEach({ (b, i, bb) in // error: "Contextual closure type '(Any) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 3 were used in closure body"
            bb[i] = -b
        })
    }
    array.forEach { (a, i, aa) in // error: "Contextual closure type '([Any]) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 3 were used in closure body"
        a.forEach({ (b, j, bb) in
            testconnection(aa, i, j) && default_value++
        })
    }
    return result_object
}
```

Any help how to fix my code would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Javascript, so it's hard to tell what your code is doing. If you want to convert `["aaa", "bbb",  "ccc"]` to nested arrays like `[["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c", "c"]]` you could just use `let array = matrix.map { Array($0) }`. If you want a one-dimensional array, use `let array = matrix.flatMap { Array($0) }`

Comment: Already found a working Solution on my own@matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you are playing Minesweeper! Here's my solution (in swift 4.0, Xcode 9.2). See inline comments for explanation.

```
let array = [
    "0000000000000000000",
    "0000001110000000000",
    "0000011111000000000",
    "0000001110000000000",
    "0000000000000000000",
    "0001100000000000000",
    "0001100000000011000",
    "0011100000000011000",
    "0000000000000000000"
]

// A structure to hold the cell's coordinate as Int array
// can become confusing very quickly
struct Cell: Equatable {
    var row: Int
    var column: Int
    var clusterIndex: Int?

    static func == (lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
        return lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.column == rhs.column
    }
}

// Get all the "1" cells
var cells = array.enumerated().flatMap { arg -> [Cell] in
    let (rowIndex, str) = arg

    // The flatMap below will become compactMap in Swift 4.1
    return str.enumerated().flatMap { colIndex, char in
        if char == "1" {
            return Cell(row: rowIndex, column: colIndex, clusterIndex: nil)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// Assign each cell a clusterIndex
for (i, currentCell) in cells.enumerated() {

    // A cell may not have all four neighbors, or not all its
    // neighbors are "1" cells, hence the "potential"
    let potentialNeighbors = [
        Cell(row: currentCell.row - 1, column: currentCell.column, clusterIndex: nil), // above
        Cell(row: currentCell.row + 1, column: currentCell.column, clusterIndex: nil), // below
        Cell(row: currentCell.row, column: currentCell.column - 1, clusterIndex: nil), // left
        Cell(row: currentCell.row, column: currentCell.column + 1, clusterIndex: nil)  // right
    ]

    // Get the actual neighboring cells and their indexes
    let neighborsAndIndexes = cells.enumerated().filter { arg in
        let (_, c) = arg
        return potentialNeighbors.contains(c)
    }
    let neighborIndexes = neighborsAndIndexes.map { $0.0 }
    let neighbors = neighborsAndIndexes.map { $0.1 }

    // Determine what clusterIndex we should give the current cell and its neighbors
    var clusterIndex = 0

    if currentCell.clusterIndex != nil {
        // If the current cell already has a clusteredIndex, reuse it
        clusterIndex = currentCell.clusterIndex!
    } else if let neighborClusterIndex = neighbors.first(where: { $0.clusterIndex != nil })?.clusterIndex {
        // If the current cell has a neighbor whose clusterIndex is not nil, use that
        clusterIndex = neighborClusterIndex
    } else {
        // Else increment from the max existing clusterIndex
        clusterIndex = (cells.map({ $0.clusterIndex ?? 0 }).max() ?? 0) + 1
    }

    // Assign the same clusterIndex to the current cell and its neighbors
    ([i] + neighborIndexes).forEach {
        cells[$0].clusterIndex = clusterIndex
    }
}

// Group the cells by their clusterIndex
let clusters = Dictionary(grouping: cells, by: { $0.clusterIndex! })
    .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
    .map { $0.value }

// Print the result
// Visualize which cell belong to which cluster and how it appears on the board
for i in 0..<array.count {
    for j in 0..<array[0].count {
        if let clusterIndex = cells.first(where: { $0.row == i && $0.column == j })?.clusterIndex {
            print(clusterIndex, terminator: "")
        } else {
            print("-", terminator: "")
        }
    }
    print() // print a newline
}
```

Result:

```
-------------------
------111----------
-----11111---------
------111----------
-------------------
---22--------------
---22---------33---
--222---------33---
-------------------
```

Note that in Swift 4.1 (currently in beta), the `flatMap` we use here has been renamed to `compactMap`. This is not to say that `flatMap` is going away completely. `flatMap` has 3 versions, only 1 of them has been renamed to `compactMap`. For more info, see [SE-0187](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md).

Comment: The solution you provided is a nice solution for my question but really not the most efficient way to find components in a matrix. A matrix format 50x/50y will probably work but with bigger matrices given - your function is **that** slow and nevertheless ineffective :(  Thanks a lot in any case!

Comment: The complexity is about O(n^2) with n being the number of "1" cells. There is a huge optimization opportunities here of course. i'll leave that to you since I don't know how big the matrix can get