# Array conversion issue

Tags: arrays, swift

I'd like to convert an multidimensional array like this:

```
var array = [
               ["10011"],
               ["11011"]
            ]
```

into an result (using Swift) like this:

```
var result = [
               [1,0,0,1,1],
               [1,1,0,1,1]
             ]
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var array = [
                ["10011"],
                ["10011"]
            ]

for var i in 0..<array.count {
    array[i][0] = (array[i][0]).characters.map { (c) -> Int in
        return c as! Int
    }
}
print(array)
```

But I'm getting this error-message:

> Cannot assign value of type '[Int]' to type 'String'

at the `map` line.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: This looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/49212921/1187415 ...

Comment: Yes thanks but Duncans solution is working fine :) @MartinR

Comment: you are using the same input array for output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
var array = [
    ["10011"],
    ["11011"]
]

let output = array.map {
    //$0[0] fetches a string from the inner array. 
    //flatMap unwraps the optionals and discards any nil results
    $0[0].flatMap { 
             //This converts each character into an Optional(Int)
             Int(String($0)) 
        }
}
```

Note that if any characters in your strings are not valid digits, they'll b dropped from the output array and that sub-array will be shorter.

If that's not what you want, change `Int(String($0))` to `Int(String($0)) ?? 0`

Also note that you can put the whole thing on one line:

```
let output = array.map { $0[0].flatMap { Int(String($0)) }
```

But that's a little harder to read.

Comment: You can (flat)map the characters without converting them to an array: `$0[0].flatMap { ... }`

Comment: So you can! (Edited)

Comment: I didn't realize that flatMap would map a `String` to an `Array` of characters, but I guess it makes sense now that a `String` is a collection again in Swift 4.